# How to hide dialled number during calling in Android

Tags: android, hide, phone-call, dialing

I want to know how to we can hide the dialed number from screen when user make any call from android device. We don't want to allow user to see the dialed number. waiting for reply..

Comment: Have you made any attempts at figuring this out?

Comment: Please show your idea/approach/tried solutions. We cannot implement a feature for you. StackOverflow can only help you with your problems.

Comment: I'd like to know what justification there is for doing such a thing. The only one I can think of is to prevent other people from seeing who you're calling, which has the simple solution of not allowing them to see your screen

Answer (score -1):

Make a new dailer view and show it on the default dailer view when user calling. Make sure to dismiss the view after call ends.